# Angular 5 - Redirect to another view if user is logged

Tags: angular

I'm using Authguard and a service called User which they don't allow the access  to certain views unless you log in.
So i found a few errors:
1) They can access to login view anyway even they are logged
(I added this code in my login.component.ts  but still doesn't work).

```
 isLog() {
if (this.user.getUserLoggedIn() === true) {

  this.router.navigate(['/products']);
} else {
 this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}}
```

1.1) If they use back/forward/refresh "automatically they log out"(it redirects to login and i have to access again.

**Authguard.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {UserService} from './user.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthguardGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private user: UserService) {}
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.user.getUserLoggedIn();
  }
}
```

**userService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  public isUserLoggedIn;
  public matricula;
  constructor() {
    this.isUserLoggedIn = false;
  }

  setUserLoggedIn() {
    this.isUserLoggedIn = true;
  }
  getUserLoggedIn() {
    return this.isUserLoggedIn;
  }
  setUserLoggedOut() {
    this.isUserLoggedIn = false;
  }
}
```

My routes(added in app.module.ts)

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login',  component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'cPanel', canActivate: [AuthguardGuard], component: CPanelComponent},
  {path: 'cPanel/producto/crearProducto', canActivate: [AuthguardGuard] , component: CrearProductoComponent},
  {path: 'productos', canActivate: [AuthguardGuard] , component: ProductosComponent},
  {path: 'cPanel/producto/modificarProducto/:id', canActivate: [AuthguardGuard], component: ModificarProductoComponent},
  {path: 'cPanel/usuario/crearUsuario', canActivate: [AuthguardGuard] , component: CrearUsuarioComponent},
  {path: 'cPanel/usuario/modificarUsuario/:id', canActivate: [AuthguardGuard] , component: ModificarUsuarioComponent},
  {path: 'cPanel/menu/modificarMenu/:id', canActivate: [AuthguardGuard], component: ModificarMenuComponent},
  {path: 'cPanel/menu/crearMenu', canActivate: [AuthguardGuard], component: CrearMenuComponent},
  {path: 'menu', canActivate: [AuthguardGuard] , component: MenuComponent},
  {path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login', canActivate: [AuthguardGuard],
    pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '**', component: E404Component},
  ];
```

Comment: How are you saving the login information? Normally, one would save it to a cookie or local storage, and the auth /user service would read that info each time the route is accessed. Also, do check if your auth service is called in the router. (show your router if you need more help)

Comment: @EdwinChua Is done, i didn't though about saving the information, is there any way i can add the local storage without modifying all?

Comment: yup. See the code I modified for an example. Although, I want to point out that a boolean login status is not the proper way to ensure your user is authenticated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Logging in by modifying your existing code slightly

Added the use of localStorage to persist your login information. This, however, might not be the best way to go about it. If you require proper user authentication, you should modify this to use a token (i.e. json web token (JWT) ) to properly verify your user.

### userService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {



public isUserLoggedIn;
  public matricula;
  constructor() {
    this.isUserLoggedIn = false;
    localStorage.setItem('login',this.isUserLoggedIn);
  }

  setUserLoggedIn() {
    this.isUserLoggedIn = true;
    localStorage.setItem('login',this.isUserLoggedIn);
  }
  getUserLoggedIn() {
    return (localStorage.getItem('login') != null ? localStorage.getItem('login') : false);
  }
  setUserLoggedOut() {
    this.isUserLoggedIn = false;
    localStorage.setItem('login',this.isUserLoggedIn);
  }
}
```

### My own Login component for reference

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  private sub: any;
  private results: any;
  title: string = "Login";
  subtitle: string = "Welcome owner";
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private http: HttpClient, private authService: AuthService, public router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.router.navigate(['write']); // if user was logged in before, redirect to default landing page
    }
  }
  onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
    var formItems = JSON.stringify(f.value);
    this.authService.login(JSON.stringify(f.value)).subscribe(data => {
      if (data) { // auth service returns boolean value
        this.router.navigate(['write']);
      }
      else {
        console.log("invalid credentials");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this error: error TS2322: Type 'string | false' is not assignable to type 'boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean>'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean>'.

Comment: if the solution works, please rmb to upvote / mark as answered :)

Comment: I found an error, if i refresh and it goes to login it doesn't let me log in

Comment: What do you mean? Open the inspector and run the command `localStorage.getItem('login')`. Is the login status set correctly?

Comment: Yeah it appears as "true", but what i meant is when i log in it doesn't redirect to certain view via form or via URL

Comment: I think there might be an issue with your login script. maybe post the whole component for us to examine. In the meantime, I've posted my own project's login component. It might be of help to you.

Answer (score 2):

**login.component.ts**

```
    constructor(
    private userService : UserService,
    private router: Router
) {
    if (this.loginService.getLogin()) {
        this.router.navigate(['product'])
    }
 }
```

This will automatically redirect you to '/product' if you accidentally go back, but won't persist if you reload the page

If you want your login data to persist (refresh, etc) you should use session storage or cookies in your userService to store your login data

**userService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

login: boolean = false;
storage: Storage;

constructor() {
    this.storage = window.localStorage;
    if (this.storage.getItem('login')) {
        this.login = this.storage.getItem('login') == 'true'
    }

 }

setLogin(val:boolean) {
    this.login = val
    this.storage.setItem('login',val == true ? 'true' : 'false')
}

getLogin() {
    return this.login
}

}
```

**EDIT :** working example on plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/XsGhXgte3woDfpKJdLxP?p=info

Also, I'm using a simple value just for the example, this is a good read about using json web tokens for auth : http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial